# How are planets distributed in elliptical galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, galaxies

I'm trying to figure out if planets are equally distributed in galaxies (I'm assuming they aren't) or if there is some logic behind their distribution.

Comment: Define 'equally distributed' here.

Comment: All of our data about planets concerns a fairly small region in the arms of a single (probably barred) spiral galaxy. We don't know anything about global distributions in any galaxy and have no data whatsoever from elliptical galaxies.